# How to invoke updating streamProvider if i send a new request data in parameter create?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have StreamProvider whiсh get data from FireStore where i passing on id of document that
i want to retrieve.

This is StreamProvider in root of widgets:

```
StreamProvider<List<TheExercise>?>(create: (_) => DatabaseService(programId: context.watch<DataChangeNotifier>().getData).exercises, initialData: null, ),
```

In "context.watch().getData" i pass id that will change depends on user activity, but i can't figure out how to rebuild streamProvider when it's get a new id.

Now stream is building one time when i listen to it.

```
final _exercises = Provider.of<List<TheExercise>?>(context)?? [];
```

Here is code in DatabaseService class:

```
        CollectionReference exercisesCollection(){
final CollectionReference _exercisesCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userData').doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid.toString()).collection('programs')
    .doc(programId).collection('exercises');
return _exercisesCollection;
```

}

```
 Stream<List<TheExercise>> get exercises {
return exercisesCollection().snapshots()
    .map((listOfExercise));
```

DataChangeNotifier class code:

```
  class DataChangeNotifier with ChangeNotifier {String _dataIdOfExercise = '';String get getData => _dataIdOfExercise;void changeIdOfExercise(String dataIdOfExercise) {
_dataIdOfExercise = dataIdOfExercise;
notifyListeners();} }
```

Comment: can you show the DataChangeNotifier

Comment: Added DataChangeNotifier code at the end of topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it replase StreamProvider on StreamProvider.value.
As i understood it takes a value every time depens on link in parameter "value".

```
StreamProvider<List<TheExercise>?>.value(value: DatabaseService(programId: context.watch<DataChangeNotifier>().getData).exercises, initialData: null),
```

But will appreciate any answers for additional knowledge.